# React + Flux: how to update store if there is a state only can be determine after component render

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I am a newbie to FLUX/REACT, and I have some question about FLUX.

Here's the scenario:

I have a store "A" and component "B", A pass data to "B" then B render it, but after B rendered, I have to save it's HTML content height to somewhere (ideally, should be in "A").

According to FLUX, the data flow should be one-way and stored in store, but I cannot know the Height before B rendered.

It's like a Paradox to me...

How should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this, your Component should dispatch an Action from your ActionCreator with the new height.

Your Store should be registered with your Dispatcher and update itself accordingly. Your Store will then emit a change event which your Component should subscribe to and update its State as needed.

Since there will be no material change for the Component to respond do, it will not re-render and your flow will end.

This is how it looks visually (View = Controller, ignore the API box for this flow):
[image: Flux Controller dispatching Actions]

https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-to-know-flux-the-react-js-architecture

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I have one more question:
Is Action in Action make sense in FLUX?
ex: store receive data from Action "x", and component update it's height via Action "y".  so the flow will be like:
x ->  A -> B -> y -> A

I am using dispatcher from [link](https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/src/Dispatcher.js).
In above case, while y dispatching, the "_isPending" will be reset to true  so any store after A will  pass x

Comment: No you cannot dispatch a new action while another dispatch is taking place. Since you essentially want to make the browser rendering your 'API' call (with the response being the rendered height), in this case I think it would be OK to use a `setTimeout` to dispatch your action. Generally however I would not recommend that approach.

Comment: So far, I don't have any other solution except "setTimeout", and I understand it's anti-pattern in FLUX. But I still wondering does no one has the problem like this case? And how will they do to overcome it?